# Get same keys from two different dictionaries

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have two different dictionaries:

```
Dictionary<int, User> X;
Dictionary<int, User> Y;
```

I want to get a list of the same keys from them using LINQ.

Answer (score 7):

```
var sameKeys = X.Keys.Intersect(Y.Keys).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend something like this:-

```
  var dict = new Dictionary<int, HashSet<string>>();
  dict.Add(1, new HashSet<string>() { "first", "second" });
```

or you can try this:-

```
  var items = new List<KeyValuePair<int, String>>();
  items.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, String>(1, "first"));
  items.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, String>(1, "second"));
  var lookup = items.ToLookup(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);

  foreach (string x in lookup[1])
  {
     Console.WriteLine(x);
  }
```